# Brezis' theorem 7.7: the case $k \ge 3$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, monotone-operator-theory

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $A: D(A) \subset H \to H$ be a maximal monotone (unbounded linear) operator. We define by induction the subspaces
$$
D(A^{k+1}) := \{ v \in D(A^k) :Av \in D(A^k)\}
\quad \forall k \in \mathbb N^*.
$$
Then $D(A^k)$ is a Hilbert space for the inner product
$$
\langle u, v \rangle_{D(A^k)} := \sum_{j=0}^k \langle A^j u, A^j v \rangle.
$$

Let $|\cdot|_{D(A^k)}$ be the induced norm of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{D(A^k)}$. I'm trying to prove the case $k\ge 3$ in *Theorem 7.7* in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $A$ be a self-adjoint maximal monotone (unbounded linear) operator. Then, given any $u_0 \in H$ there exists a unique function
> $$
> u \in C([0,+\infty) ; H) \cap C^1((0,+\infty) ; H) \cap C((0, +\infty); D(A))
> $$
> such that
> $$
> (*) \quad\begin{cases}
> \frac{d u}{d t}+A u&=0 \quad \text{on} \quad (0,+\infty), \\
> u(0)&=u_0.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Moreover, we have
>
> - $|u(t)| \leq\left|u_0\right|$ and $\left|\frac{d u}{d t}(t)\right|=|Au(t)| \leq \frac{1}{t} \left|u_0\right|$ for all $t > 0$.
> - $u \in C^{k-\ell} ((0,+\infty) ; D(A^\ell))$ for all $k \in \mathbb N^*$ and $\ell=0, \ldots, k$.

I have proved for the case $k=1$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741019/brezis-theorem-7-7-uniqueness-and-existence) and for the case $k=2$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741122/brezis-theorem-7-7-the-case-k-2). There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

We argue by induction on $k \ge 2$: assume that the result holds up to order $(k-1)$. We want to prove
$$
u \in C^{k-\ell} ((0,+\infty) ; D(A^\ell))
\quad \forall \ell = 0, \ldots,k.
$$

From the case $k=2$, we know that
$$
u \in C^2 ((0, +\infty); H) \cap C^1((0, +\infty); D(A)),
$$
and that $u$ satisfies
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left (\frac{d u}{d t} \right )+A \left (\frac{du}{dt} \right )=0 \quad \text{on} \quad (0,+\infty).
$$

Let
$$
v :=\frac{d u}{d t}.
$$

Then $v \in C^1 ((0, +\infty); H) \cap C((0, +\infty); D(A))$. Let $t_0>0$. Then
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{d v}{d t}+A v &= 0 \quad \text{on} \quad (t_0,+\infty), \\
v(t_0) &= -A u(t_0).
\end{cases}
$$

Then the restriction of $v$ to $[t_0, +\infty)$ is the solution of $(*)$ with the initial data $v(t_0) = -A u(t_0)$. By inductive hypothesis,
$$
v \in C^{k-1-\ell} ((t_0,+\infty) ; D(A^\ell))
\quad \forall \ell = 0, \ldots,k-1.
\tag{1}
$$

This implies
$$
u \in C^{k-\ell} ((t_0,+\infty) ; D(A^\ell))
\quad \forall \ell = 0, \ldots,k-1.
$$

It remains to check that
$$
u \in C ((t_0,+\infty) ; D(A^k)).
\tag{2}
$$

Applying (1) with $\ell=k-1$, we get
$$
\frac{du}{dt} \in C ((t_0,+\infty) ; D(A^{k-1})).
$$

Then by $(*)$
$$
Au \in C ((t_0,+\infty) ; D(A^{k-1})).
$$

Notice that
$$
|x|_{D(A^k)}^2 = |x|^2 + |Ax|_{D(A^{k-1})}^2
\quad \forall x \in D(A^k).
$$

Then (2) follows. Because $t_0>0$ is arbitrary, the proof is completed.

Comment: Your proof seems correct to me. But why didn't you use a similar proof to the case $k=2$?

Comment: @Kroki Actually I mimicked the proof of *Theorem 7.5* where the author first proves for the case $k=2$ and then proves by induction for $k \ge 3$. I will think about your suggestion.

Comment: Ah I see. But you can mimic the proof of case $k=2$ by considering $H_1 = D(A^{k-1})$ instead of $D(A)$ and you will have a similar proof.

Comment: @Kroki Could you have a check on my answer below? Do you think that it can be further simplified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Kroki in a comment, we can treat the case $k=2$ and $k\ge 3$ simultaneously.

---

We argue by induction on $k \ge 2$: assume that the result holds up to order $(k-1)$.
In particular,
$$
u \in C ((0,+\infty) ; D(A^{k-1})). \tag{1}
$$

We want to prove
$$
u \in C^{k-\ell} ((0,+\infty) ; D(A^\ell))
\quad \forall \ell = 0, \ldots,k.
$$

Consider the Hilbert space $H_1 = D(A^{k-1})$ equipped with the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{D(A^{k-1})}$. Then the operator $A_1 :D(A_1) \subset H_1 \to H_1$ defined by
$$
\begin{cases}
D(A_1) &= D(A^k), \\
A_1 u &= Au,
\end{cases}
$$
is maximal monotone and self-adjoint.

Fix $t_0 >0$. By (1), $u(t_0) \in H_1$. We apply the case $k=1$ to the operator $A_1$ in the space $H_1$, we see that there is a unique function
$$
\overline u \in C ([t_0, +\infty); H_1) \cap C^1 ((t_0, +\infty); H_1) \cap C((t_0, +\infty); D(A_1))
$$
that satisfies
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{d \overline u}{d t}+A \overline u &= 0 \quad \text{on} \quad (t_0,+\infty), \\
\overline u(t_0) &= u(t_0).
\end{cases}
\tag{2}
$$

Since $A \in \mathcal L(H_1, H)$ and $\overline u \in C^1 ((t_0, +\infty); H_1)$, we get $A\overline u \in C^1 ((t_0, +\infty); H)$ and
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (A\overline u) = A \left (\frac{d\overline u}{dt} \right )
\quad \text{on} \quad (t_0, +\infty).
$$

By (2), $\frac{d \overline u}{d t} \in C^1 ((t_0, +\infty); H)$ and thus  $\overline u \in C^2 ((t_0, +\infty); H)$. Also,
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left (\frac{d \overline u}{d t} \right )+A \left (\frac{d\overline u}{dt} \right )=0 \quad \text{on} \quad (t_0,+\infty).
$$

By uniqueness, $u$ and $\overline u$ coincide on $[t_0, +\infty)$. Let
$$
v :=\frac{d u}{d t}.
$$

We have just shown above that
$$
v \in C^1 ((t_0, +\infty); H) \cap C((t_0, +\infty); H_1),
$$
and
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{d v}{d t}+A v &= 0 \quad \text{on} \quad (t_0,+\infty), \\
v(t_0) &= -A u(t_0).
\end{cases}
$$

If $t_1 > t_0$, then $v \in C ([t_1, +\infty); H_1)$. So $v \in C ([t_0, +\infty); H_1)$. Notice that $H_1 \subset D(A) \subset H$. Thus
$$
v \in C ([t_0, +\infty); H) \cap C^1 ((t_0, +\infty); H) \cap C((t_0, +\infty);  D(A)).
$$

Then the restriction of $v$ to $[t_0, +\infty)$ is the solution of $(*)$ with the initial data $v(t_0) = -A u(t_0)$. By inductive hypothesis,
$$
v \in C^{k-1-\ell} ((t_0,+\infty) ; D(A^\ell))
\quad \forall \ell = 0, \ldots,k-1.
\tag{3}
$$

This implies
$$
u \in C^{k-\ell} ((t_0,+\infty) ; D(A^\ell))
\quad \forall \ell = 0, \ldots,k-1.
$$

It remains to check that
$$
u \in C ((t_0,+\infty) ; D(A^k)).
\tag{4}
$$

Applying (3) with $\ell=k-1$, we get
$$
\frac{du}{dt} \in C ((t_0,+\infty) ; D(A^{k-1})).
$$

Then by $(*)$
$$
Au \in C ((t_0,+\infty) ; D(A^{k-1})).
$$

Notice that
$$
|x|_{D(A^k)}^2 = |x|^2 + |Ax|_{D(A^{k-1})}^2
\quad \forall x \in D(A^k).
$$

Then (4) follows. Because $t_0>0$ is arbitrary, the proof is completed.

Comment: Yes it seems correct to me and I think it is simple.

Comment: @Kroki Thank you so much for your dedicated support. I'm trying to use the same technique to treat simultaneously the cases $k=2$ and $k \ge 3$ in the proof of *Theorem 7.5*.

Comment: Ok that would be good to do.