# Brezis' theorem 7.5: a simplified proof

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, semigroup-of-operators, monotone-operator-theory

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $A: D(A) \subset H \to H$ be a maximal monotone (unbounded linear) operator. We define by induction the subspaces
$$
D(A^{k+1}) := \{ v \in D(A^k) :Av \in D(A^k)\}
\quad \forall k \in \mathbb N^*.
$$
Then $D(A^k)$ is a Hilbert space for the inner product
$$
\langle u, v \rangle_{D(A^k)} := \sum_{j=0}^k \langle A^j u, A^j v \rangle.
$$

Then we have from Brezis' *Functional Analysis* two theorems, i.e.,

> **Theorem 7.4 (Hille-Yosida)** Let $A: D(A) \subset H \to H$ be a maximal monotone (unbounded linear) operator. Then, given any $u_0 \in D(A)$ there exists a unique function
> $$
> u \in C^1([0,+\infty) ; H) \cap C([0,+\infty) ; D(A))
> $$
> satisfying
> $$
> (*) \quad \begin{cases}
> \frac{d u}{d t}+A u&=0 \quad \text{on} \quad [0,+\infty), \\
> u(0)&=u_0.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Moreover,
> $$
> |u(t)| \leq\left|u_0\right| \quad \text { and } \quad\left|\frac{d u}{d t}(t)\right|=|A u(t)| \leq\left|A u_0\right| \quad \forall t \geq 0.
> $$

and

> **Theorem 7.5** Assume $u_0 \in D (A^k)$ for some integer $k \geq 2$. Then the solution $u$ of problem $(*)$ obtained in **Theorem 7.4** satisfies
> $$
> u \in C^{k-j} ([0,+\infty) ; D (A^j)) \quad \forall j=0,1, \ldots, k.
> $$

The author proves **Theorem 7.5** by first considering the case $k=2$ and then by induction for $k \ge 3$. From a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741158/brezis-theorem-7-7-the-case-k-ge-3#comment10055185_4741158) by @Kroki, I would like to treat the cases $k=2$ and $k \ge 3$ simultaneously.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

We argue by induction on $k \ge 2$: assume that the result holds up to order $(k-1)$.

Consider the Hilbert space $H_1 = D(A^{k-1})$ equipped with the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{D(A^{k-1})}$. Then the operator $A_1 :D(A_1) \subset H_1 \to H_1$ defined by
$$
\begin{cases}
D(A_1) &= D(A^k), \\
A_1 u &= Au,
\end{cases}
$$
is maximal monotone.

We have $u_0 \in D(A_1)$. We apply *Theorem 7.4* to the operator $A_1$ in the space $H_1$, we see that there is a unique function
$$
u \in C^1([0,+\infty) ; H_1) \cap C([0,+\infty) ; D(A_1))
$$
such that
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{d u}{d t}+A u &= 0 \quad \text{on} \quad [0,+\infty), \\
u(0) &= u_0.
\end{cases}
\tag{1}
$$

Notice that $H_1 \subset H$ and $D(A_1) \subset D(A)$. Then
$$
u \in C^1([0,+\infty) ; H) \cap C([0,+\infty) ; D(A))
$$

It follows from (1) that $u$ satisfies $(*)$. By uniqueness, $u$ is *the* solution of $(*)$.

Since $A \in \mathcal L(H_1, H)$ and $u \in C ([0, +\infty); H_1)$, we get $Au \in C^1 ([0, +\infty); H)$ and
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (A u) = A \left (\frac{d u}{dt} \right )
\quad \text{on} \quad [0, +\infty).
$$

By $(*)$, $\frac{d u}{d t} \in C^1 ([0, +\infty); H)$ and thus  $u \in C^2 ([0, +\infty); H)$. Also,
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left (\frac{d u}{d t} \right )+A \left (\frac{d u}{dt} \right )=0 \quad \text{on} \quad [0,+\infty).
$$

Let
$$
v :=\frac{d u}{d t}.
$$

We have just shown above that
$$
v \in C^1 ([0, +\infty); H) \cap C([0, +\infty); H_1),
$$
and
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{d v}{d t}+A v &= 0 \quad \text{on} \quad [0,+\infty), \\
v(0) &= -A u_0.
\end{cases}
$$

Then $v$ is the solution of $(*)$ with the initial data $v(0) = -A u_0$. By inductive hypothesis,
$$
v \in C^{k-1-j} ([0,+\infty) ; D (A^j)) \quad \forall j=0,1, \ldots, k-1.
\tag{2}
$$

This implies
$$
u \in C^{k-j} ([0,+\infty) ; D (A^j)) \quad \forall j=0,1, \ldots, k-1.
$$

It remains to check that
$$
u \in C ([0,+\infty) ; D(A^k)).
\tag{3}
$$

Applying (2) with $\ell=k-1$, we get
$$
\frac{du}{dt} \in C ([0,+\infty) ; D(A^{k-1})).
$$

Then by $(*)$,
$$
Au \in C ([0,+\infty) ; D(A^{k-1})).
$$

Notice that
$$
|v|_{D(A^k)}^2 = |v|^2 + |Av|_{D(A^{k-1})}^2
\quad \forall v \in D(A^k).
$$

Then (3) follows. This completes the proof.

Comment: It seems correct to me!

Comment: @Kroki Thank you so much again! You support means a lot to me.